# How can I get a random ordering of a list of unique Strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, user-interface, random

I have 12 strings in an ArrayList.  I want to display these string randomly in a textarea.  I've gotten to where the strings show up randomly, but they repeat sometimes. I don't want them to repeat at all until its gone through all 12 strings. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * Layout of the application
 * 
 *  ###############################
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ##          #####            ##
 *  ##          #####            ##
 *  ##          #####            ##
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ###############################
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ##         Text Area         ##
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ###############################
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ##  #Fortune#       #Quit#   ##
 *  ##                           ##
 *  ###############################
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Kelle Schmitt
 */
public class FortuneTellerFrame extends JFrame
{
    public FortuneTellerFrame()
    {
    //set width and height of the window
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;

    //set width and height of the text area
    final int AREA_ROWS = 10;
    final int AREA_COLUMNS = 25;

    //declare the panels that are going to be used.
    final JPanel mainPnl, titlePnl, textPnl, controlPnl;
    final JLabel fortuneImage;

    //declare and find image for what your title/title image will be?
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/1804-1-bad-fortune-teller.jpg");
    fortuneImage = new JLabel("Fortune Teller!", icon, JLabel.CENTER);
    fortuneImage.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
    fortuneImage.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

    //declare the buttons that are going to be used.
    final JButton futureBtn, quitBtn;

    //create the main panel, and add the other panels to it
    mainPnl = new JPanel();
    mainPnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    titlePnl = new JPanel();
    textPnl = new JPanel();
    controlPnl = new JPanel();

    mainPnl.add(titlePnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPnl.add(textPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPnl.add(controlPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //add the main panel to the parent frame
    add(mainPnl);
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //add other componets to the sub panel
    titlePnl.add(fortuneImage);

    final JTextArea fortuneArea;
    fortuneArea = new JTextArea(AREA_ROWS, AREA_COLUMNS);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fortuneArea);
    fortuneArea.setText("I will tell the future...");
    textPnl.add(scrollPane);

    futureBtn = new JButton("Read my Fortune!");
    quitBtn = new JButton("Quit");

    controlPnl.add(futureBtn);
    controlPnl.add(quitBtn);

    //create actionlisteners for the buttons
    class QuitButtonListener implements ActionListener 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    ActionListener quitListener = new QuitButtonListener();
    quitBtn.addActionListener(quitListener);

        class ReadMyFortuneListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {            
            ArrayList<String> fortunes = new ArrayList<>();
            fortunes.add("The Browns will win the Super Bowl. Just Kidding the will never happen.");
            fortunes.add("You will get an A++ in Programming this semester!");
            fortunes.add("You will die in a very humorous way.");
            fortunes.add("You will fall in love with Kyle Hurt.");
            fortunes.add("You will be attacked by Aliens in the near future.");
            fortunes.add("You will be eaten by an alligator while walking to class today.");
            fortunes.add("You will go pro in football.");
            fortunes.add("Steve Jobs will come back from the dead to give you 1 billion dollars.");
            fortunes.add("You are going to disappear and never be heard from again.");
            fortunes.add("You are going to win a lifetime of moonshine.");
            fortunes.add("A bag of sugar will fall on you in the store today.");
            fortunes.add("You get to be the frountman of your favorite band.");


            Random rand = new Random();
            int pick = rand.nextInt(fortunes.size());
            fortuneArea.setText(fortunes.get(pick));

        }
    }
        ActionListener futureTeller = new ReadMyFortuneListener();
        futureBtn.addActionListener(futureTeller);
    }



}
```

Comment: Instead of using a random index, you could simply shuffle your list: `Collections.shuffle(fortunes);` and loop over it.

Comment: @user3235565: Please reduce your code to the relevant size. There is no need to include a GUI for such a question.

Comment: shuffle's FAR better - it'll automatically handle having to watch for duplicates, because you'll just be going through the list in index order. shuffle the list once, iterate through the list, and boom. all fortunes output with no dupes, in random order.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: It was a homework question. I already turned it in waiting for a grade.  I just wanted to see actually how to do it before I went and sought personal help from the instructor. That's why I can't use collections.shuffle

Answer (score 3):

Use the Collection shuffle static method to shuffle your numbers:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ShuffleNumbers {
    static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            list.add(new Integer(i));
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all!
you must put your `arraylist` as field in FortuneTellerFrame  class:
here is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> fortunes = new ArrayList<>();
public FortuneTellerFrame()
{            
        fortunes.add("The Browns will win the Super Bowl. Just Kidding the will never happen.");
        fortunes.add("You will get an A++ in Programming this semester!");
        fortunes.add("You will die in a very humorous way.");
        fortunes.add("You will fall in love with Kyle Hurt.");
        fortunes.add("You will be attacked by Aliens in the near future.");
        fortunes.add("You will be eaten by an alligator while walking to class today.");
        fortunes.add("You will go pro in football.");
        fortunes.add("Steve Jobs will come back from the dead to give you 1 billion dollars.");
        fortunes.add("You are going to disappear and never be heard from again.");
        fortunes.add("You are going to win a lifetime of moonshine.");
        fortunes.add("A bag of sugar will fall on you in the store today.");
        fortunes.add("You get to be the frountman of your favorite band.");
```

and in the actionPerform you must remove the element each time you find it. here is the code:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pick = rand.nextInt(fortunes.size());
        fortuneArea.setText(fortunes.get(pick));
        fortunes.remove(pick)
    }
```